# Is there any way to add custom variant to Typography?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The typography object comes with 13 variants by default:

```
h1
h2
h3
h4
h5
h6
subtitle1
subtitle2
body1
body2
button
caption
overline
```

So, Is there any way to add custom variant so that I can use this like below example:-

```
<Typography variant={'content1'}>Content1 goes here...</Typography>
<Typography variant={'content2'}>Content2 goes here...</Typography>
```

And could define `content1` and `content2` in theme:-

```
createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        content1: {
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontSize: 12,
            lineHeight: '18px',
        },
        content2: {
            fontWeight: 600,
            fontSize: 14,
            lineHeight: '22px',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it only for semantic and consistency? Or you ok with add a component which extends `Typography`.

Comment: Anyway, I'll put it here. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-c0f92?file=/demo.js